# Building a war with dependencies in an external lib folder

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, dependencies, war, maven-plugin

My war file gets really big and I would like to build it as I do for jars: packaging dependencies in a lib folder outside the war, so as to keep the war small in size. Transfer time to my server will be much improved.

I have not found a question on SA addressing this specific issue. I wonder:

- is it technically possible, or is there something in Jakarta EE which forbids this way to pack dependencies?
- if possible, is there a Maven plugin for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jakarta EE is using a concept of installed library mechanism.
Installed libraries are visible to all WAR files.

More details you can find [here](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/8/platform-spec-8.html#installed-libraries).

So, you can move all the JARs that are not part of your source code like Spring, Hibernate, etc. to Jakarta installed libraries and deploy a much light-weight WARs.

Comment: Thank you! Your answer lead me to search for how this would work on Payara micro, and for anyone interested, here is the doc: https://docs.payara.fish/community/docs/documentation/payara-micro/adding-jars.html